# GCP vm connect local server

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have stage/prod project. I have setup the VPN for connecting local server and VPC in stage. They can ping each other. But Now I want to the VM in prod can connect my local server as well. What can I do ? BTW I have setup the VPC peering.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details about you use case ? Is the production VM in the same VPC as the staging one ? Please describe your network topology better.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question isn't very detailed I will make some assumptions as for your infrastructure.

As I understand you have staging server in GCP in one VPC (lets call it vpc1), and production server in another VPC (vpc2). You also have on-premise server (lets call this network lan) connected to a staging one (vpc1) using VPN.

Like this: `lan --> vpc1 ---> vpc2`

There are two ways I can think of.

1. Easy and proven way - create another VPN tunnel from lan to vpc2 (production) and that's it.
2. Create VPC peering between vpc1 & vpc2. Then create VPN tunnel from lan to vpc1. Your on-premise router must be configured to send all traffic intended for vpc2 to VPN tunnell. Furthermore you need to set up VPC peering with import/export routes enabled at both ends in peering connection. You also must cofigure static route direct all packets going from lan to vpc1 (which will in turn send them to vpn tunnel).

Create  VPC peering connection with flags:

```
    --import-custom-routes
      If set, the network will import custom routes from peer network. Use
      --no-import-custom-routes to disable it.
```

and

```
    --export-custom-routes
      If set, the network will export custom routes to peer network. Use
      --no-export-custom-routes to disable it.
```

Here's some documentation on [how to set up access to peered network using VPN](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/google-cloud-networking-in-depth-simplify-routing-between-your-vpcs-with-vpc-peering) and about [On-premises access from peer network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#on-premises_access_from_peer_network).

And finally some [troubleshooting tips here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering):

> **Q: How do I make routes in a peer network available to an on-premises
> network connected to my VPC network using Cloud VPN or Cloud
> Interconnect?**
>
> VPC Network Peering does not support transitive routing; that is,
> imported routes from other networks are not automatically advertised
> by Cloud Routers in your VPC network. However, you can use custom IP
> range advertisements from Cloud Routers in your VPC network to share
> routes to destinations in the peer network.
>
> For Classic VPN tunnels using static routing, you must configure
> static routes to the peer network's destination ranges in your
> on-premises network. Note that certain use cases of Classic VPN
> tunnels are deprecated.

Comment: Hello @Wojtek_B
Thank you for your reply. Sorry for late reply.
your assumption is exactly right:

lan --> vpc1 <--(vpc peering)--> vpc2

In stage project, my current Cloud VPN is classic type with static IP in the VPC routing to local Vigor router with Policy-based type and then reach to on-premise server. 

Regarding to the second way, you meant no matter what the project is.  just send all traffic to the VPN tunnel which I already have?

I am wondering the second way is less money for setup compared to the first one? 
If yes. Will it be a better choice ?

Comment: If you set up 2nd VPN tunnel (pair actually...) then it [will cost you slightly more](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/pricing) but it's a tested fool-proof solution. But you can save money (if you have more time on your hands) nad configure routing correctly. But this poses security issues due to direct access from prod network to staging net. I don't recommend that - but that however depends on your use case.

Comment: After I already enabled the import and export custom route 
[pic](https://imgur.com/sw6GRXB) for the both projects. And I add the routing policy on-premise Draytek router which destination IP range is prod VPC(vpc2) subnet directed to the stage VPN, but they still can not connect.

Comment: Did you add the route in prod-network and on-premise lan ? The both have to "know" how to reach each other.

Comment: yes. I saw the route with IP range 192.168.1.0/24 (Auto generated route via peering [production-to-stage]) in prod network and also route all Traffic to 10.0.0.0/16 which is prod VPC by VPN on-premise lan

Comment: If you can (for security reasons) can you provide detailed network (on-prem, staging & prod); IP's routing, VPN configuration ? Without them I can't troubleshoot this further...

Comment: Hello @Wojtek_B
I already added the pic of current network  in my questions. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Can your prod network talk to stage ?

Comment: yes. By peering

Comment: Can you actually provide the real routes (screens, snippets, logs) that will tell how you''ve set up the routing. Judging from the model it's OK but it's better double check those things.